# How to save annotations in pdftron in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, annotations, pdftron

I need to upload PDF , highlight some text, add annotation note for the highlighted text and save edited PDF along with highlighted text & annotation notes in Nodejs. I'm using [PDFTron](http://pdftron.com/) in this regard and its doing fine till uploading, highlighting and writing note for highlighted part but unable to save the data.

What I get from [PDFTron guide](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/tutorials/getting-started-annotations.html) is that clicking the save button of the note container (to which I'm considering annotation If I'm not wrong) will send 'POST Request' to the server URL for saving the note. It hits the server URL on page reload for loading the saved annotations but don't send any POST request on the same server URL for saving annotations on clicking save button.

Here's my webviewer initialization code:

```
var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
    type: "html5",
    path: "/lib",
    initialDoc: "/GettingStarted.pdf",
    serverUrl: "/annotations", //server URL to save & load annotation
    documentType: docType,
    config: "/lib/config.js",
    documentId: "GettingStarted",
    enableAnnotations: true,
    useDownloader: false,
    streaming: false
}, viewerElement);
```

Please point out If I misunderstood any step or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console after pressing the save button? Can you try adding a breakpoint to BaseReaderControl.js in the exportAnnotations function as that's where the post request is made from and you can see if that code is getting called or erroring out for some reason.

Comment: There's no error on clicking the save button. Seems save button isn't calling any function for saving annotations. I haven't edited BaseReaderControl.js yet. will give it a look

Answer (score 1):

In the annotation side bar there is a pull-down menu(arrow down icon) where you click and the save button is displayed there. Knowing this, it is not user friendly so create you own button and fire it manually.
You can fire it manually with:

```
myWebViewer.instance.saveAnnotations();
```